# ASP.Net MVC 2.0 Client Validation with Castle Validators

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, castle

Im trying to implement a client and server validation for my webapplication using castle valitors.Has anyone got any examples of how to use Castle Validators with ASP.net mvc v2 Client validation.

Comment: Are you aware that this is built-in to MVC2?

http://hadihariri.com/blogengine/post/2009/10/06/Client-Side-Validation-in-MVC-20.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I have a good blog post on how to impliment a custom provider for Validation in MVC 2.0.
http://www.bitsinmyhead.com/2010/09/asp-net-mvc-2-0-and-its-validation%E2%80%A6-using-a-custom-provider/